# Call recording voice is low at receiver end Android

Tags: android, mediarecorder, call-recording

I have this call recording built in with in app,the problem is if person A  Call to person B ,the person A sound is loud and clear but the person B is sound so low,but it's working perfect with android 7 & 8 Os ,But due to call recording restrictions from the android 9 and 10,the B person sound is low in android 9 and 10

i tested some call recorder app in android 9 and 10,it have same problems,but i came across this app[Call Recorder - Cube ACR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catalinagroup.callrecorder&hl=en_IN),it also have problem,but when i change record setting to voice Call (Software) like in the picture,after changing this recording is so much clear

Can any guide me to how to resolve this i tired lot things,i can't see the end,Ps:This is setting changed
in the app[image]

This is the project is used [aykuttasil/CallRecorder](https://github.com/aykuttasil/CallRecorder)

This is what i tried for recording the call

```
  callRecord = new CallRecord.Builder(this)
            .setRecordFileName("Record_" + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date()))
            .setRecordDirName("CallRecord")
            .setRecordDirPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath())
            .setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
            .setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB)
            .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION)
            .setShowSeed(true)
            .buildService();

    callRecord.startCallRecordService();
```

Please Help me on this

Answer (score 2):

I'm using AccessibilityService + MediaRecorder. It is working for me.

AccessibilityService - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64058109/12427903)

Here is my code

```
recorder = MediaRecorder()
recorder?.apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT)
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
                setAudioSamplingRate(44100)
                setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000)
            }else{
                setAudioSamplingRate(8000)
                setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200)
            }
            setOutputFile(audioFile!!.absolutePath)
            setOnErrorListener { _, _, _ -> }
        }
recorder?.prepare()
```